# Dúvida sobre uma questão de String (Linguagem C)

Tags: c, string

Queria tirar um dúvida sobre um questão de String, a atividade pede para que eu Imprima um frase que foi digitada em ordem alfabética, colocando cada palavra da frase em ordem. Porém, quando dou Run no programa e digito a frase, dependendo do tamanho dela, nem todas palavras são colocadas em ordem, parece que existe um erro de limitação. Não sei como arrumar isso, segue o código abaixo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
char nm1[100], nm2[100], nm3[100], con;

        char alf[100] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','x','w','y','z','\0'};
        char alfb[100] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','X','W','Y','Z','\0'};
        
        printf("Digite uma frase: ");
        scanf("%s", &nm1);

        scanf("%s", &nm2);
        
        printf("Frase em ordem alfabetica: ");
        scanf("%s", &nm3);

        for(con = 0; con < 100; con++)
        {
            if(nm1[0] == alf[con]|| nm1[0] == alfb[con])
                printf(" %s", nm1);
            if(nm2[0] == alf[con]|| nm2[0] == alfb[con])
                printf(" %s", nm2);
            if(nm3[0] == alf[con]|| nm3[0] == alfb[con])
                printf(" %s", nm3);    
        }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Explique melhor o que deseja fazer. Se a frase foi digitada em ordem alfabética o que significa "colocar as palavras da frase em ordem"? Note que da maneira como está lendo a frase (`scanf` com formato `%s`) sua frase não conterá espaços pois ele delimita e encerra a leitura da string.

Answer (score 0):

Seu código possui alguns erros:

O `scanf()` espera receber um ponteiro para a variável a ser lida, como um vetor por si só já é um ponteiro `&nm1` não é necessário, algo como `scanf("%s", nm1)` funcionaria melhor. Porém o argumento `"%s"` lê uma string até o espaço ou quebra de linha(ENTER), e acredito que sua frase possua vários espaços.
Para ler a linha inteira eu recomendo o comando `fgets()` que irá ler até uma quebra de linha(ENTER), obs: ele adiciona o valor '\n' no fim de sua string.

Recomendo também que faça a verificação se uma letra é maior que a outra através da tabela ASCII.

Letras de A-Z são representadas por números do 65 até 90 e de a-z 97 até 122.

Para converter um char para ASCII `int x = (int)'a'`

[Tabela Ascii](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif)